# What is Unified Inbox in android?

Tags: android, messaging

What is unified inbox ? I like to know more about it. 
Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was talking about messages. I got the answer. It is an inbox which contains all type of messages like sent messages, inbox messages, draft messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

A unified inbox, I would assume you're talking about email, is just an inbox that contains mail from multiple email accounts aggregated into one. I can't really say much because you haven't really specified much. I don't really think this is the appropriate place to ask this question.